# How to switch between built-in "General" screen and Application Activity on DP7?

Tags: android, keyboard, raspberry-pi3, android-things

It's possible on DP7 to switch to built-in "General" screen:

[image: Built-in "General" screen]

via <kbd>Esc</kbd> (`keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK`) press on external USB keyboard, but how to switch back from built-in "General" screen to Application Activity (seems Application still working with "General" screen on top)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good way to relaunch your app after returning to the launcher. You would need to do a device reboot or redeploy your app from Android Studio over ADB.

The features that you may want in the launcher: Wi-Fi, peripheral information, etc. should all be accessible through public APIs, allowing you to control the device from within your application. Essentially, you should implement your own launcher (or whatever type of application you are building).